# How to adjust times by adding hours to every cell in a column VBS macro

Tags: excel, time, vba

OK what i have is this: Our data system logs everything in UTC time, the reports that i need to write need to be in local time which is UTC+8 hours

I can increase the time in a cell with this formula in VB

```
Sub UTC+8()
    With Range("A1")
        .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(8, 00, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```

How do i apply this to a whole column of times? Ive tried ("A:A")
but i couldn't get it to function correctly.

The time values are stored as simple 00:00:00 with no dates involved.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is **VBA** solution that you can adapt:

```
Sub UTC8x()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        With r
            .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(8, 0, 0)
        End With
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Most excellent answer :o)
Only error it spat back was type mismatch in debug for .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(8, 0, 0)
but this was down to cells in the range of a differnt format. Easly fixed.

Thank you Gary